# R - removing white spaces using the format() function

Tags: r, shiny, format, whitespace, space

In my Shiny app, I am trying to print a value which in reality is an amount of money.

The code at the moment is as follows:

```
text <- reactive({format(data()), big.mark= ",", trim = 
"TRUE")})

output$profit <- renderText({
paste("The total profit is \u00a3",text(),".")
```

However, there is still white spaces before and after the value that is returned from `text()`. How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition, we can use `glue::glue`

```
glue("The total profit is \u00a3{text()}")
```

-fullcode

```
library(shiny)
library(glue)

options(scipen = 999)
df1 <- data.frame(amount = c(5000, 10000, 200000))
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("amt", "amount", choices  = df1$amount),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "profit")

)
server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive(as.numeric(input$amt))

text <- reactive({
   format(data(), big.mark= ",", trim = TRUE)})

output$profit <- renderText({
  glue("The total profit is \u00a3{text()}")

})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Experiment a little with the paste function and note the `sep` argument from the documentation:

```
paste("The total profit is \u00a3","5,000",".")
[1] "The total profit is £ 5,000 ."
```

This would suggest the problem is independent of what's coming out of `text()`.  Instead:

```
paste("The total profit is \u00a3","5,000",".",sep = "")
[1] "The total profit is £5,000."
```

You might also be interested in the package **lucr** which is convenient for styling currencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste0` which can remove white spaces between strings.

Or as @joran said, add `sep=""` option in `paste`.